# recompile 32-bit library

Tags: windows, ubuntu, 64-bit, compilation

I want to know how or using what could I recompile a 32-bit library to make it work on 64-bit, I have access to the source code, I just want to know how this could be done.

Thanks!

It doesn't matter if it's using ubuntu or windows, to compile, I don't have preferences.

It's in the C language!!

Answer (score 0):

You don't say what IDE you are using, but there should be an option to target a 64-bit operating system.

For Visual Studio you select **Build > Configuration Manager...** and then change the "Platform" from "Any CPU" or "x86" to "x64".

You can then look in the project file to see what compile options have been added/changed.

As an aside, if it's a Windows application it should still work without recompiling. 64-bit Windows will run 32-bit applications.

Comment: Yes I know visual studio I'm goint to check there!

Answer (score 0):

Note that changing a pulldown from "32" to "64" may not be enough if there are assumptions made about pointer and word size in the code. These sorts of issues will have to be detected through proper testing protocols.